# Urql svelte does not add query parameter properly

Tags: graphql, svelte, urql

I get this error when initializing a query with urql

> [GraphqlQL] must provide query

I checked the payload in the network tab and it looks like urql removed the query keyword from the request payload this is how it looks like in the network tab:

```
query:  {\n  categories {\n    name\n    id\n    __typename\n  }\n}
```

This is my query in the svelte file, it's copied from the documentation exactly

```
const categories = operationStore(`
      query {
        categories{
          name
          id
        }
      }
      `)
```

this is the payload generated in graphiql
`query: "query{\n  categories{\n    id\n    name\n  }\n}"`

any help would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to preprocess queries using the `gql` facility provided by urql:

```js
import { gql } from '@urql/svelte';

const categories = operationStore(gql`
  query {
    categories {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`);
```

If your queries start becoming more complex, or if you start handling multiple different queries, I recommend putting them in their own separate file(s) (`$lib/queries.js` is as good a place as any), for example in your case:

```js
// $lib/queries.js
import { gql } from '@urql/svelte';

export const GET_CATEGORIES = gql`
  query {
    categories {
      name
      id
    }
  }
`;

// in your component:
import { GET_CATEGORIES } from '$lib/queries';

const categories = operationStore(GET_CATEGORIES);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer unfortunately it didn't solve my problem I still get the same exact error